# Restructure the Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of objects which I need to restructure. The input array of objects is as follows:

```
[
 [
  {
    "lat": 51.00445965809624,
    "lng": 5.505536355741434
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00431971638806,
    "lng": 5.505461423372382
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00417977463196,
    "lng": 5.505386491455417
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00403983282792,
    "lng": 5.505311559990534
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00389989097598,
    "lng": 5.505236628977724
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00375994907609,
    "lng": 5.505161698416986
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00362000712828,
    "lng": 5.505086768308312
  }
],
[
  {
    "lat": 51.00440846173839,
    "lng": 5.505785160705168
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00426821144456,
    "lng": 5.505709911534925
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00412796110243,
    "lng": 5.50563466281968
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00398771071194,
    "lng": 5.5055594145594275
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00384746027312,
    "lng": 5.505484166754162
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00370720978598,
    "lng": 5.5054089194038776
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.0035669592505,
    "lng": 5.50533367250857
  }
],
[
  {
    "lat": 51.004357264852146,
    "lng": 5.506033965119733
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00421670597403,
    "lng": 5.505958399145694
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.004076147047186,
    "lng": 5.505882833629572
  }, 
  {
    "lat": 51.003935588071585,
    "lng": 5.505807268571363
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00379502904726,
    "lng": 5.505731703971063
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.003654469974194,
    "lng": 5.5056561398286625
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00351391085237,
    "lng": 5.505580576144162
  }
],
[
  {
    "lat": 51.00430606743754,
    "lng": 5.506282768985127
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00416519997647,
    "lng": 5.506206886204688
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00402433246626,
    "lng": 5.506131003885096
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00388346490688,
    "lng": 5.506055122026344
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00374259729837,
    "lng": 5.505979240628427
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.00360172964068,
    "lng": 5.505903359691342
  },
  {
    "lat": 51.003460861933874,
    "lng": 5.505827479215082
  }
]
]
```

In actuality these are the coordinates of pitch blocks here as below:
[image]

If you see there are four row lines ( each block has two up and down ) and seven column lines ( each block has two, left and right line). so array has four main array and seven objects under that.

Can I get the structure of array so that it should be like the coordinates of each block in array? e.g.

```
[
  [


[
   { lat: 51.00445965809624, lng: 5.505536355741434 },
   { lat: 51.00431971638806, lng: 5.505461423372382 },
   { lat: 51.00426821144456, lng: 5.505709911534925 },
   { lat: 51.00440846173839, lng: 5.505785160705168 },
   { lat: 51.00445965809624, lng: 5.505536355741434 }
  ],[
    ....
  ]
] ,[
    ....
  ]
]
```

Below array structure, if for bottom left block number 54.

```
[
    [


 [
   { lat: 51.00445965809624, lng: 5.505536355741434 },
   { lat: 51.00431971638806, lng: 5.505461423372382 },
   { lat: 51.00426821144456, lng: 5.505709911534925 },
   { lat: 51.00440846173839, lng: 5.505785160705168 },
   { lat: 51.00445965809624, lng: 5.505536355741434 }
  ],[
    ....
  ]
] ,[
        {},{}..
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to iterate the original array and make the "box" combinations. There are many ways to do that. Here is how you can use `flatMap` and `map` to perform the nested iteration along row/column dimensions:

```js
const points = [[{"lat": 51.00445965809624,"lng": 5.505536355741434},{"lat": 51.00431971638806,"lng": 5.505461423372382},{"lat": 51.00417977463196,"lng": 5.505386491455417},{"lat": 51.00403983282792,"lng": 5.505311559990534},{"lat": 51.00389989097598,"lng": 5.505236628977724},{"lat": 51.00375994907609,"lng": 5.505161698416986},{"lat": 51.00362000712828,"lng": 5.505086768308312}],[{"lat": 51.00440846173839,"lng": 5.505785160705168},{"lat": 51.00426821144456,"lng": 5.505709911534925},{"lat": 51.00412796110243,"lng": 5.50563466281968},{"lat": 51.00398771071194,"lng": 5.5055594145594275},{"lat": 51.00384746027312,"lng": 5.505484166754162},{"lat": 51.00370720978598,"lng": 5.5054089194038776},{"lat": 51.0035669592505,"lng": 5.50533367250857}],[{"lat": 51.004357264852146,"lng": 5.506033965119733},{"lat": 51.00421670597403,"lng": 5.505958399145694},{"lat": 51.004076147047186,"lng": 5.505882833629572}, {"lat": 51.003935588071585,"lng": 5.505807268571363},{"lat": 51.00379502904726,"lng": 5.505731703971063},{"lat": 51.003654469974194,"lng": 5.5056561398286625},{"lat": 51.00351391085237,"lng": 5.505580576144162}],[{"lat": 51.00430606743754,"lng": 5.506282768985127},{"lat": 51.00416519997647,"lng": 5.506206886204688},{"lat": 51.00402433246626,"lng": 5.506131003885096},{"lat": 51.00388346490688,"lng": 5.506055122026344},{"lat": 51.00374259729837,"lng": 5.505979240628427},{"lat": 51.00360172964068,"lng": 5.505903359691342},{"lat": 51.003460861933874,"lng": 5.505827479215082}]];

const boxes = points.slice(1).flatMap((row, y) => 
    row.slice(1).map((_, x) => [
        ...points[y].slice(x, x + 2),
        ...row.slice(x, x + 2)
    ])
);

console.log(boxes);
```

Note that the same object will be used multiple times in the output, as an object represents a point that can be shared by up to four neighboring boxes. In the above stack snippet output, this reuse of the same objects is marked with `/*id*/` and `/*ref*/` comments.

Comment: Hello @trincot, there is a change in the question, I have updated the required structure. Can you please look into it? the third element should be on the fourth position. Actually I am looking to make it a square block.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't like to work on a moving target. If I spend more time on this you might decide to change the question again and again. Sorry, but I don't like questions that change after answers have been posted.

Comment: should I accept this answer and post a new question ? but this is the final requirement.

Comment: Asking a new question is always a possibility. Whether you mark this answer as accepted depends on whether it was useful to you with reference to how the original question was stated. It certainly is not a must and you shouldn't feel pressured to do so.

Comment: I have accepted the answer and will ask a new question

Comment: I have added question here on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74262967

Comment: can you please check the question here on above link. I have updated.