# modify the object data as coordinates to make them as square block

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
this.gridcrds = [
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00445965809624,
      "lng": 5.505536355741434
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00431971638806,
      "lng": 5.505461423372382
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00417977463196,
      "lng": 5.505386491455417
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00403983282792,
      "lng": 5.505311559990534
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00389989097598,
      "lng": 5.505236628977724
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00375994907609,
      "lng": 5.505161698416986
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00362000712828,
      "lng": 5.505086768308312
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00440846173839,
      "lng": 5.505785160705168
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00426821144456,
      "lng": 5.505709911534925
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00412796110243,
      "lng": 5.50563466281968
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00398771071194,
      "lng": 5.5055594145594275
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00384746027312,
      "lng": 5.505484166754162
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00370720978598,
      "lng": 5.5054089194038776
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.0035669592505,
      "lng": 5.50533367250857
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.004357264852146,
      "lng": 5.506033965119733
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00421670597403,
      "lng": 5.505958399145694
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.004076147047186,
      "lng": 5.505882833629572
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.003935588071585,
      "lng": 5.505807268571363
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00379502904726,
      "lng": 5.505731703971063
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.003654469974194,
      "lng": 5.5056561398286625
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00351391085237,
      "lng": 5.505580576144162
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00430606743754,
      "lng": 5.506282768985127
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00416519997647,
      "lng": 5.506206886204688
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00402433246626,
      "lng": 5.506131003885096
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00388346490688,
      "lng": 5.506055122026344
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00374259729837,
      "lng": 5.505979240628427
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00360172964068,
      "lng": 5.505903359691342
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.003460861933874,
      "lng": 5.505827479215082
    }
  ]
]
```

This is the image of pitch which has blocks and each block has coordinates as given in above array:
[image]
and the following code is doing them restructure but not making a square block.

```
  this.blocksVertices = this.gridsCrds.slice(1).flatMap((row: any, y: any) =>
        row.slice(1).map((_: any, x: any) => [
        ...this.gridsCrds[y].slice(x, x + 2),
        ...row.slice(x, x + 2)
    ]));
```

and provides me with the following result:

```
[
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00445965809624,
      "lng": 5.505536355741434
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00431971638806,
      "lng": 5.505461423372382
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00440846173839,
      "lng": 5.505785160705168
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00426821144456,
      "lng": 5.505709911534925
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00431971638806,
      "lng": 5.505461423372382
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00417977463196,
      "lng": 5.505386491455417
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00426821144456,
      "lng": 5.505709911534925
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00412796110243,
      "lng": 5.50563466281968
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00417977463196,
      "lng": 5.505386491455417
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00403983282792,
      "lng": 5.505311559990534
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00412796110243,
      "lng": 5.50563466281968
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00398771071194,
      "lng": 5.5055594145594275
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00403983282792,
      "lng": 5.505311559990534
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00389989097598,
      "lng": 5.505236628977724
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00398771071194,
      "lng": 5.5055594145594275
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00384746027312,
      "lng": 5.505484166754162
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00389989097598,
      "lng": 5.505236628977724
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00375994907609,
      "lng": 5.505161698416986
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00384746027312,
      "lng": 5.505484166754162
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00370720978598,
      "lng": 5.5054089194038776
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00375994907609,
      "lng": 5.505161698416986
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00362000712828,
      "lng": 5.505086768308312
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00370720978598,
      "lng": 5.5054089194038776
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.0035669592505,
      "lng": 5.50533367250857
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00440846173839,
      "lng": 5.505785160705168
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00426821144456,
      "lng": 5.505709911534925
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.004357264852146,
      "lng": 5.506033965119733
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00421670597403,
      "lng": 5.505958399145694
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00426821144456,
      "lng": 5.505709911534925
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00412796110243,
      "lng": 5.50563466281968
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00421670597403,
      "lng": 5.505958399145694
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.004076147047186,
      "lng": 5.505882833629572
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00412796110243,
      "lng": 5.50563466281968
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00398771071194,
      "lng": 5.5055594145594275
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.004076147047186,
      "lng": 5.505882833629572
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.003935588071585,
      "lng": 5.505807268571363
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00398771071194,
      "lng": 5.5055594145594275
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00384746027312,
      "lng": 5.505484166754162
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.003935588071585,
      "lng": 5.505807268571363
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00379502904726,
      "lng": 5.505731703971063
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00384746027312,
      "lng": 5.505484166754162
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00370720978598,
      "lng": 5.5054089194038776
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00379502904726,
      "lng": 5.505731703971063
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.003654469974194,
      "lng": 5.5056561398286625
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00370720978598,
      "lng": 5.5054089194038776
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.0035669592505,
      "lng": 5.50533367250857
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.003654469974194,
      "lng": 5.5056561398286625
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00351391085237,
      "lng": 5.505580576144162
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.004357264852146,
      "lng": 5.506033965119733
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00421670597403,
      "lng": 5.505958399145694
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00430606743754,
      "lng": 5.506282768985127
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00416519997647,
      "lng": 5.506206886204688
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00421670597403,
      "lng": 5.505958399145694
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.004076147047186,
      "lng": 5.505882833629572
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00416519997647,
      "lng": 5.506206886204688
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00402433246626,
      "lng": 5.506131003885096
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.004076147047186,
      "lng": 5.505882833629572
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.003935588071585,
      "lng": 5.505807268571363
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00402433246626,
      "lng": 5.506131003885096
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00388346490688,
      "lng": 5.506055122026344
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.003935588071585,
      "lng": 5.505807268571363
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00379502904726,
      "lng": 5.505731703971063
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00388346490688,
      "lng": 5.506055122026344
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00374259729837,
      "lng": 5.505979240628427
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.00379502904726,
      "lng": 5.505731703971063
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.003654469974194,
      "lng": 5.5056561398286625
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00374259729837,
      "lng": 5.505979240628427
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00360172964068,
      "lng": 5.505903359691342
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "lat": 51.003654469974194,
      "lng": 5.5056561398286625
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00351391085237,
      "lng": 5.505580576144162
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.00360172964068,
      "lng": 5.505903359691342
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.003460861933874,
      "lng": 5.505827479215082
    }
  ]
]
```

It should be in the following format. Third object should be at the fourth position. and first object should be on the last position as well.

```
 [
  [
   { lat: 51.00445965809624, lng: 5.505536355741434 },
   { lat: 51.00431971638806, lng: 5.505461423372382 },
   { lat: 51.00426821144456, lng: 5.505709911534925 },
   { lat: 51.00440846173839, lng: 5.505785160705168 },
   { lat: 51.00445965809624, lng: 5.505536355741434 }
  ],
  [
   { "lat": 51.00431971638806,"lng": 5.505461423372382 },
   { "lat": 51.00417977463196,"lng": 5.505386491455417 },
   { "lat": 51.00412796110243,"lng": 5.50563466281968  },
   { "lat": 51.00426821144456,"lng": 5.505709911534925 },
   { "lat": 51.00431971638806,"lng": 5.505461423372382 }
  ],
  [
     ...
  ],
  [ 
     ...
  ]
 ]
```

Can I update this array of objects so that I can make square blocks on google map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the current output and the desired output is that the current output gives the four unique points of the square in the order (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right), while the desired output has the first point repeated at the end, and follows a clockwise order: (top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left, top-left).

So change the existing code to call `.reverse()` on the two bottom points, and add the first point to the inner array:

```
this.blocksVertices = this.gridsCrds.slice(1).flatMap((row, y) =>
    row.slice(1).map((_, x) => [
    ...this.gridsCrds[y].slice(x, x + 2),
    ...row.slice(x, x + 2).reverse(), // <-- reversed order
    this.gridsCrds[y][x]              // <-- add top-left again
]));
```

As a runnable snippet:

```js
this.gridsCrds = [[{"lat": 51.00445965809624,"lng": 5.505536355741434},{"lat": 51.00431971638806,"lng": 5.505461423372382},{"lat": 51.00417977463196,"lng": 5.505386491455417},{"lat": 51.00403983282792,"lng": 5.505311559990534},{"lat": 51.00389989097598,"lng": 5.505236628977724},{"lat": 51.00375994907609,"lng": 5.505161698416986},{"lat": 51.00362000712828,"lng": 5.505086768308312}],[{"lat": 51.00440846173839,"lng": 5.505785160705168},{"lat": 51.00426821144456,"lng": 5.505709911534925},{"lat": 51.00412796110243,"lng": 5.50563466281968},{"lat": 51.00398771071194,"lng": 5.5055594145594275},{"lat": 51.00384746027312,"lng": 5.505484166754162},{"lat": 51.00370720978598,"lng": 5.5054089194038776},{"lat": 51.0035669592505,"lng": 5.50533367250857}],[{"lat": 51.004357264852146,"lng": 5.506033965119733},{"lat": 51.00421670597403,"lng": 5.505958399145694},{"lat": 51.004076147047186,"lng": 5.505882833629572},{"lat": 51.003935588071585,"lng": 5.505807268571363},{"lat": 51.00379502904726,"lng": 5.505731703971063},{"lat": 51.003654469974194,"lng": 5.5056561398286625},{"lat": 51.00351391085237,"lng": 5.505580576144162}],[{"lat": 51.00430606743754,"lng": 5.506282768985127},{"lat": 51.00416519997647,"lng": 5.506206886204688},{"lat": 51.00402433246626,"lng": 5.506131003885096},{"lat": 51.00388346490688,"lng": 5.506055122026344},{"lat": 51.00374259729837,"lng": 5.505979240628427},{"lat": 51.00360172964068,"lng": 5.505903359691342},{"lat": 51.003460861933874,"lng": 5.505827479215082}]];

this.blocksVertices = this.gridsCrds.slice(1).flatMap((row, y) =>
    row.slice(1).map((_, x) => [
    ...this.gridsCrds[y].slice(x, x + 2),
    ...row.slice(x, x + 2).reverse(),
    this.gridsCrds[y][x]
]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(this.blocksVertices, null, 2));
```

Comment: no sir,  it is giving the follownig :  
{ lat: 51.00445965809624, lng: 5.505536355741434 },​​
{ lat: 51.00431971638806, lng: 5.505461423372382 },
{ lat: 51.00440846173839, lng: 5.505785160705168 },
{ lat: 51.00426821144456, lng: 5.505709911534925 },​​
{ lat: 51.00445965809624, lng: 5.505536355741434 },​​
{ lat: 51.00445965809624, lng: 5.505536355741434 }

Comment: Can you be clear about what exactly is the difference. All those digits are just floating around. It would be so much simpler if you would use dummy integer values so that it is clear what you expect. I am honestly too tired to compare each number digit by digit.

Comment: I think no need to use `this.gridsCrds[y][x]`

Comment: My code produces an array of subarrays where the inner subarrays have 5 objects. You show me 6 objects without array. I don't understand where you get that from.

Comment: sir your code works !!! Thanks a lot. you save my day.

Comment: Why did you remove the 5th object from my answer's code? You only want 4 objects in each subarray? You lost me now... I rolled back your edit.

Comment: No I need five, but your code without this.gridsCrds[y][x]   is giving expected object

Comment: So... my code as posted (with `this.gridsCrds[y][x]`) generates 5. Proof is in the runnable snippet I just added to my answer now. If you remove that part, then you only have 4 objects in each subarray as each `slice` represents 2 objects. I don't know what you did at your side, but you must be doing something different than I posted.